# Create android project by Command prompt for android studio version 2.2.3

Tags: android-studio

I want to create android project by Command prompt  for android studio version 2.2.3. 
My android studio Tools folder is in 
C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\m2repository\com\android\ . 
And my android projects are saved in in C:\Users\USER\AndroidStudioProjects\ .

I have tried either of this two paths in command prompt and then typed 
android create project \ --target 1 \ --name MyAndroidApp \ --path ./AndroidStudioProject \ --activity MyAndroidAppActivity \
--package com.example.myandroid

it shows in command prompt as:

'android' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program 
or batch file.

What should I do or type in command prompt to create an android project as a basic or empty project in android studio 2.2.3 by using command line for the criteria I provided in this topic.

Answer (score 1):

The command you want is in your android sdk directory, wherever you have it installed. So if your android directory is in c:\sdk then you would have the c:\sdk\tools\android create project